# PyTorch geometric train_test_split_edges implemented on dataset with edge features crashes the google-colab notebook

Tags: graph, google-colaboratory, data-preprocessing, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am new to PyTorch Geometric. While I was splitting my dataset (  data size => Data(x=[14254, 1647], edge_index=[2, 8552], edge_attr=[8552, 8])  )  using train_test_split_edges  from pytorch geometric the [google-colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17TrjHLKhTaEvb04BhQtlgRM0ksbkjqpg#scrollTo=oxeCNsDGZh04) crashes without any indication on the reason of this crash.
My questions :

- Why is this happening ?
- How can I fix this ?
- Should I implement a custom train_test_split_edges  for my large dataset ?
- How can I implement a custom train_test_split_edges ?

Best regards,
Chiheb